# Google Maps V3 - Issue with removing markers and updating clusters

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

First off, thanks to everybody that contributes to this website. I am no expert, but I've learnt so much from this community :)

I have a google map with a custom menu that allows the user to filter categories in a particular area, adding markers to the map depending on what categories are selected. The markers are added to an array called 'markers' when visible. Every thing seemed to be working fine, but then I added the markercluster.js plugin and my problems began. When markers from a category are removed from the map, they don't get removed from the markers array. This seems to have a knock on effect to the clusters numbers as they do not update when markers are removed, only when they are added.

```
        // The navigaiton item that has been clicked 
        $(source + ' .map-controls ul li a').live('click', function(e){
            // The category of the clicked item eg. hikes, kayaking etc
            var markerClass = $(this).attr('class');
            // If the clicked items is not visible on the map
            if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('visible')) {
                // Go through JSON to find matching categories
                for(i=0; i<category.length; i++) {
                    // If we find a match to the category of the clicked item
                    if(category[i].mapmarker == markerClass){
                        // Grab the latitude and longitude
                        var lat = category[i].lat;
                        var long = category[i].long;
                        // Create a position variable
                        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
                        latslongs.push(myLatlng);
                        // Create the marker
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: myLatlng,
                            map: map
                        });
                        // Give the marker and id of the category clicked
                        marker.setValues({type: "point", id: markerClass});
                        // Set the category to the category clicked
                        marker.mycategory = markerClass;
                        // Push the marker to the markers array
                        markers.push(marker);           
                    }
                }
                // Marker Cluster options - Bonus point if you can tell me why opt_textColor and opt_anchor don't work?
                mcOptions = {styles: [{
                    opt_textColor: 'white',
                    height: 47,
                    url: "http://localhost/img/bgs/bg-marker-cluster.png",
                    width: 46,
                    opt_anchor: [5, 12]
                }]}
                // Set up MarkerCluster
                var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
                // Make the markers visible on the map
                $(this).parent().addClass('visible');

            } else {
                    // ELSE - If the clicked categories markers are visible when clicked, we go through the array of all the markers currently visible on the map
                    for (i=0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                        // If we find a match to the clicked category
                        if(markers[i].get('id') == markerClass){
                            // HERE IS WHERE I HAVE MY PROBLEM!!
                            // This line works as in it removes the correct markers from the map, but not from the markers array.
                            // I've seen suggestions of markers.lenght = 0 but I can't do that as I have others markers on the map
                            markers[i].setMap(null);
                            // I only found this out when adding the cluster plugin. Before it seemed to be working perfectly but 
                            // I had no idea the array just kept growing in size while showing/hiding different categories.
                            // I have tried so many things to try and remove the correct array items from the array, but I can't get it.
                            // The other issue is that the cluster numbers are not updating when removing categories??? But they get higher
                            // everytime you add a category. This might be a knock on effect of the ever growing markers array.
                        }
                    }
                    // Make the markers invisible on the map
                    $(this).parent().removeClass('visible');

            }
            // Thanks guys and girls.
            e.preventDefault();

        });

    },
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is my first time using the google api so am a little lost and would love some advice or pointers. I've tried so many things including what seems to be an accepted method of setting the markers array to 0 but that does not work for me in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this must be because the variable marker scope is not global so when removing the script can not access the marker variable

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is that you're simply setting the markers not to show

```
markers[i].setMap(null);
```

I think you need to also add some logic to remove the individual marker from the array of markers, like so:

```
//remove the marker from the map
markers[i].setMap(null);
//remove the marker from the array
markers.splice(i, 1);
```

This will probably require you to manage them in another array if you wish to keep track of them in memory.

Alternatively, you could manage multiple instances of MarkerClusterer, one for each type.  Then you could just call

```
markerCluster.clearMarkers();
```

Bonus (opt_textColor & opt_anchor):
I believe your variables should just be "textColor" & "anchor":

- 'styles': (object) An object that has style properties:
    ...

  - 'anchor': (Array) The anchor position of the label text.
  - 'textColor': (string) The text color.